# How can I to check a property will be renewed or its value will be changed

Tags: c#, properties

How can I to check a property will be renewed or its value will be changed.

```
public MyClass A
{
   get{} 
   set
      {
          // find if programmer set A=new MyClass(); 
      }
}
```

Comment: You may implement INotifyPropertyChanged : see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

Comment: By your question it seems that you want to check if the value provided is different from the value already stored. Is this correct?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Yes. I want to know is the property renewed and my aliases was broken or not.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus It seems I was chose the wrong name to tag, excuse me ;) 
RaphaëlAlthaus  implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged is the right answer but it is more expensive than my problem. then I prefer to ignore it.

Comment: [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)?

Answer (score 1):

It's not all clear what you want exactly, maybe something like this:

```
MyClass _a;
public MyClass A
{
    get { return _a; }
    set
    {
        // find if programmer set A=new MyClass();
        if (value != _a)
        {
            // different value
        }
    }
}
```

For more complex scenario follow the suggestion of  Raphaël Althaus and take a look at [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).